# How to make an image hidden then appear at a certain time

Tags: javascript, image

I am not really a coder but I'm trying to run some basic javascript on a landing page builder (Samcart) so that an image will be hidden then appear after the user has been onpage for a certain length of time.

I have tried a few things. So far, I was able to bring in the image from imgur successfully. So I can display it fine. I'm just struggling to know what javascript code to use.

I found some javascript code that should enable this for me:

```
<script>
  $("div").hide();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("div").show();
  },3000);
</script>
```

This is the code I created on the page to pull the image from imgur:

```
<div class="valuestack">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TrGitqf.png" width="60000" height="1300">
</div>
```

I honestly don't really know what I'm doing and need some clarification.

Thank you in advance,
Nathan

Comment: The order that your code gets executed in depends on where you put it on the page.  I would make sure your script is after the div tags and also recommend using the $(document).ready function, as it looks like this is jquery

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Nathan here is a JavaScript solution to your problem.

You are using setTimeout() function which expects a function to be passed to it.
The syntax of the above function is as below -

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('valuestack').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}, 2000);
```

Additionally, instead of hiding it through JavaScript/JQuery, you might consider just applying a CSS style to handle it being hidden by default (i.e. display: none) and then simply showing it within the body of your setTimeout() function call.

```js
function showImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("valuestack") != null) {
    document.getElementById('valuestack').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('valuestack').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }, 2000);
  }
}

showImage();
```

```css
.v-image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.v-stack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="valuestack" class="v-image v-stack">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TrGitqf.png" width="600" height="1300" >
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the help! I was able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted uses [jQuery](https://jquery.com).  You will need to include jQuery on the page for it to work.

Also, this code will hide and show all `<div>` elements on your page.  You'll probably want to change the code to target `div.valuestack` instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things here

1. You need to include JQuery as below. (there are more methods to include, this is just one way)`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. The method that you have written in script tag is never called. So this small code must be called when your landing page is load.

   `<script>
       window.onload = function() {
          $(".valuestack").hide();
          setTimeout(function() {
           $(".valuestack").show();
          }, 3000);
       }
    </script>`